# Is there any operator which its spectrum corresponding to a compact set?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras

we know that for each operator $T$ the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is compact. Is the converse true I mean if we have a compact set $K\neq\emptyset$, is there any operator $T$ such that $\sigma(T)=K$?

I am searching for counterexample.

thanks

Comment: You need $K$ to be nonempty.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you do not specify the space, the answer is yes. Take $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and let $f$ be a measurable function such that its range is exactly your compact set, i.e. $f(\mathbb{R})=K$. Then the spectrum of the multiplication operator with $f$ equals your prescribed compact set.

The multiplication operator with $f$ is defined as $M_f g := fg$ for all $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. In this case, $\sigma(M_f)=K$.

ADDED:
The spectrum of the multiplication operator is calculated [here in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298899/the-norm-and-the-spectrum-of-blpx-mu).

Comment: did you prove it or say an example,but any way thank you for your example

Comment: Do you need something else?

Comment: Is it true generally? so we have to give a proof, if not we should say a counterexample!

Comment: I gave you the the steps of the proof that it is true. Do you need any point here to be clarified? I assumed that you know the concepts I mention, but this may not be the case.

Comment: you said a multiplication operator!it means $\sigma(M_{\phi}(f))=K$?where $\phi$ is in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: I edit the answer to this point.

Comment: where is the $M_{g}(f):=gf$?

Comment: can you calculate the spectrum of that?

Comment: The idea is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_operator

Comment: someone added something interesting!now we have to prove $E_{g}=K$??

Comment: I added it. You have complete freedom in choosing your function. So choose it so that $E_g=K$.